# is there a way to remind someone posting a question to mark the version number in the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to remind someone posting a question to mark the version number in the question?

it is getting tiring to have to ask each time what version number they are using.

At the Maple own forum, they have a nice menu there, where one needs to indicate the Maple version number when posting a question.

[image]

How could something like this be done here?

Comment: Of less importance but also of frequent issue is the OS being used.

Comment: Finally someone recognizes this as an issue, too! I've been trying to advocate for this for a [long time](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/should-indicating-the-version-of-mma-be-compulsory).

Comment: Is it possible to have a set of required tags? For instance, `'OS'` and `'Version'`?